# Cascade Palm - Leaves and trunk going brown

Tags: leaves

[image][image]

Hi,

I’m just hoping to get some advice on my cascade palm.   I have noticed that the leaves and trunk are starting to go Brown with brown blotches and spots all throughout.  Am I doing something wrong here and what can I do to remedy this ?

Thanks

Sonny

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a lot of fine debris on some of the leaflets - I can't tell if you've dropped something on the plant or whether its something like mealybug and frass, but the debris ranges from black bits to white bits which might well be mealybugs, especially as there's some white fluffy areas. Assuming you haven't dropped or spilt something on the plant, get a magnifying glass and inspect the leaves closely, including at the base where the stems originate. If it is mealybug, you can use isopropyl alcohol to clean them off, but you'll probably need to spray with neem or similar too, see here https://www.hunker.com/12507363/how-to-get-rid-of-mealy-bugs-on-palms

If this palm is indoors, it should be kept out of direct sunlight; browning of the trunk could be connected with over or underwatering. How often do you water and how much do you give it? If the plant is in an outer pot or tray, do you empty that out 30 minutes after you've watered, or just leave it sitting in water? I'm assuming the pot it's in has drainage holes...

Answer (score 1):

Check the soil for water saturation. If your soil is heavy or clay-like, try adding some sand or peat moss. Finger check by poking a few inches down and check the soil moisture if the soil is cool and dry you need water. Palms are also Picky eaters when it comes to essential nutrients, they need manganese, iron and sulfur in their diet. Palm based fertilizers are essential, failing that citrus fertilizer will do